# Inflate Layout but keep current content

Tags: android

Im working on a Chat app and I need to append elements but keeping the content as I add more.

My code (new message arrive):

```
layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content);    
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
int id = R.layout.messages;

RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(id, null, false);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.topMargin = 15;
relativeLayout.setPadding(5, 3, 5, 3);  
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

layout.addView(relativeLayout);
```

This add all the content inside "messages.xml" but replaces the old content.

Imagine it's a chat application and I need to append content (new messages) but still showing the old content (old messages)

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use a ListView? And each new Message will be a new element in your ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have followed your question- are you trying to attach a child view to the RelativeLayout? If so you want to do something along the lines of:

```
   RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.content);
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.messages, null);
    item.addView(child);
```